# How does Python inheritance detection work?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-import

I have a base class, and several sub classes that inherit from it. I am trying to detect dynamically which sub classes inherit from the base class dynamically. I am currently doing it by dynamically importing all the sub classes in the base class `__init__()`, and then using the `__subclasses__()` method.

I have the following file structure:

```
proj/
|-- __init__.py
|-- base.py
`-- sub
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- sub1.py
    |-- sub2.py
    `-- sub3.py
```

base.py:

```
import importlib

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        importlib.import_module('sub.sub1')
        importlib.import_module('sub.sub2')
        importlib.import_module('sub.sub3')

    @classmethod
    def inheritors(cls):
        print(cls.__subclasses__())

b = Base()

b.inheritors()
```

sub1.py:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

from base import Base

class Sub1(Base):
    pass
```

sub2.py:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

from base import Base

class Sub2(Base):
    pass
```

and finally sub3.py:

```
import sys
import os

class Sub3(object):
    pass
```

You will notice that `sub.sub1.Sub1` and `sub.sub2.Sub2` both inherit from `base.Base` while `sub.sub3.Sub3` does not.

When I open IPython3, and run `import base` I get the following output:

```
In [1]: import base
[<class 'sub.sub1.Sub1'>, <class 'sub.sub2.Sub2'>]
```

The output above is exactly as I would expect it to be. It gets weird when I run base.py using Python command line:

```
python3 base.py
[<class 'sub.sub2.Sub2'>]
[]
```

Now I think that I understand that there are two prints in the second case because the Python importer initially does not see `base.py` in the `sys.modules` global variable, so when a subclass is imported it will import `base.py` again and the code will be executed a second time. This explanation does not explain why the first time it prints `[<class 'sub.sub2.Sub2'>]` and not `[<class 'sub.sub1.Sub1'>]` as `sub.sub1.Sub1` is imported first, and it does not explain why only `sub.sub2.Sub2` appears in the `__subclasses__()` while `sub.sub1.Sub1` does not.

Any explanation that would help me understand how Python works in this regard will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I would like to run the module using `python base.py`, so maybe I can be pointed in the correct direction for that?

Comment: Short answer: don't use circular imports, and don't treat the same file as a script and an importable module. This kind of craziness is what happens when you do those things. Also, `__subclasses__` isn't very useful, since it only knows about subclass definitions that have actually been executed.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to understand the behavior. This is not production ready code. In general, I know and agree with what you say, but I am asking for a deeper understanding of the internals of Python.

Comment: Do you have an alternative to `__subclasses__()` that does know my subclasses before they are executed?

Comment: Static code analysis tools can help with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a knot. 
A complicated, uneeded knot. I could figure it out - but I don't know if I can keep it in mind to explain what is going on in a clear way  :-)

But one thing first: this has less to do with "inheritance detection", andvall to do with the import system - which you tied in a complicated knot.

So, you get the unexpected result because when you do `python base.py`, the contents of base are recorded as the module named `__main__` in `sys.modules`. 
Ordinarily, Python will never import the module and run the same code again: upon fiding an import statement that tries to import an existing module, it just creates a new variable poiting to the existing module. If that module did not finish the execution of its body yet, not all classes or variables will be seem on the place where there is the second import statement. Calls to importlib do no better - they just don t automate the variable biding part. When you do circular imports, change the import path, and import a module named  `base` from another file, Python does not know this is the same `base` that is `__main__`. So, the new one gets a new fresh import, and a second entry in sys.modules,as  `base`.

If you just print the `__class__` in your inheritors method, it will be clear:

```
@classmethod
def inheritors(cls):
    print("At class {}. Subclasses: {}".format(__class__, cls.__subclasses__()))
```

Then you will see that "base.Base" has the "sub2" subclass and `__main__.Base`  has no subclasses.

Now, let me try to put the timeline for it:

1. `base.py` is imported as  `__main__` and runs up to the line `b =
   Base()`. At this point the `__init__` method of Base will import the
   submodules
2. submodule `sub1` is run, changes the sys.path, and
   re-imports base.py as the `base` module.
3. The contents of the
   base module are run until the `__init__` method in base.Base is met;
   therein, it imports `sub.sub1`,and Python finds out this module has
   already been imported and is in `sys.modules`. Its code has not been
   completed, and the `Sub1` base is not yet defined, though.
4. Inside the sub1 import of base, `__init__` tries to import `sub.sub2`. That
   is a new module to Python, so it is imported
5. On the import of
   `sub2`, when `import base` is met, Python recognizes the module as
   imported already (although, again, not all the initialization code
   is complete)- it just brings the name alias to sub2 globals, and
   keeps on
6. Sub2 is defined as subclass of `base.Base`
7. `sub.sub2` import finishes, and Python resumes to the `__init__` method on step (4); Python imports sub.sub3 and resumes to the  `b.inheritors()` call
   (from `base`, not from `main`). At this point the only subclass of
   `base.Base` is `sub2` - that is printed
8. The importing of
   `base.py` as `base` finishes, and Python resumes executing the bodu
   of `sub.sub1`- class `Sub1` is defined as a subclass of `base.Base`
9. Python resumes the `__main__.base.__init__` execution, imports
   sub.sub2 - but it is already run, the same for `sub.sub3`
10. `__main__.Base.inheritors` is called in `__main__`, and prints no
    sub-classes.

And that is the end of a complicated history.

## What you should be doing

first: if you need to do the `sys.path.append` trickery, there is something wrong with your package. Let your package be `proj`, and point `proj.__init__` to import `base` if you want that to be run (and dynamically import the other modules) - but stop fidling with sys.path to find things in your own package.

second: 
the `cls.__subclasses__` call is of little use, as it will only tell you about the imediate subclasses of `cls` - if there is a grand-chid subclass it will go unoticed,

The most usual pattern is to have a register of subclasses of your Base - an as they are created, just add the new classes to this record. This can be done with a metaclass, in Python < 3.6, or with the `__init_subclass__` method on Python 3.6 and on.